# What are the necessary conditions for a polynomial Q(X) such that the roots of Q(X) - X are equal to the real roots of a polynomial P?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, roots, fixed-points

If $P(X), Q(X) ∈ ℝ[X]$ , and $P(X) | P( Q(X) ) $ , what could be the necessary conditions for $Q(X)$ such that the set of the real roots of $P(X) $ to be equal to the set of the real roots of $Q(X) - X $( i.e. the set of fixed points of the polynomial function of $Q(X)$ ) ?

Comment: Can you explain the question with an example, say, with the polynomial $Q(X)=X$?

Comment: The example I used when I asked myself this question was actually when Q(X)=X^2. More specific, if we had P(X) to be a real monic polynomial, with simple roots, such that P(X^2) = ± P(X) *P(-X), I found out that the only such possibilities are P(X)=X, P(X)=X-1, or P(X)=X(X-1). I was wondering if I could somehow find a generalisation to this problem, I don't know if that makes any sense...

Answer (score 0):

One necessary condition is that $Q$ does not induce a permutation without fixed points on any finite subset of $\mathbb R$, i.e. there does not exist a finite set 
$S \subset \mathbb R$ such that $Q(S) = S$ but $Q(s) \ne s$ for all $s \in S$.
Namely, if such $S$ existed we could take $P(X) = \prod_{s \in S} (X - s)$.

Comment: I was wondering, could this condition actually be equivalent to the polynomial function Q being strictly monotone on the interval Im(Q) ? The left to right implication is certainly true, however I’m not quite sure about the right to left one...